# Octane level for rental car

Tags: car-rentals

Hi I've been using a rental car for the past few days and it's a full to full type of deal. They asked me to fill it up with 95 octane fuel. This seems to me like a bit overkill, I'm wondering if I save some money and put in regular will they have any way of knowing?

Comment: Is this Europe? In Europe 95 (RON) is regular gasoline.

Comment: if they tell you to use 95, use 95. They will have a good reason for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about car maintanance, not about travel.

Comment: @Willeke I have to disagree. This is a situation which arose only because the person is traveling, not just because they need to put petrol in a car. I can easily see someone from another continent (like that big one west of the Atlantic where they do lots of things strangely) being confused by this and needing to ask.

Comment: Many people use rental cars at home. There is no indication that this is a travel related question.

Comment: Here in UK 95 octane is regular, 97 octane is super. You can't get less than 95 octane. If you can get less than 95 octane in the unstated country, they will know if the car doesn't then run properly.

Comment: There's a big difference between filling an almost empty tank with low grade (which may cause problems) and topping off the tank with a few percent just before returning (highly unlikely to do anything wrong but won't save you much). Which is closer to your case?

Comment: There are more than one way to measure octane number. In Europe and elsewhere RON is used, while in the US, Canada and some other countries AKI, aka PON and (R+M)/2 is standard.

Comment: A European rating of 95 (RON) would in the US be circa 90 (AKI).